# "$\leq_\Bbb{R}$" is restriction of "$\leq_{\overline{\Bbb{R}}}$" to $\Bbb{R}$ ?!

Tags: real-numbers

In definition of [Affinely Extended Real Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffinelyExtendedRealNumbers.html), I think that "$\leq_\Bbb{R}$" is [restriction](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aRestriction/Relation) of "$\leq_{\overline{\Bbb{R}}}$" to $\Bbb{R}$

Is it correct?... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Christoph, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define $\le_{\overline{\mathbb R}}\;\subseteq \overline{\mathbb R}\times\overline{\mathbb R}$ as
$$
\le_{\overline{\mathbb R}}\quad=\quad\le_{\mathbb R}\ \cup\ \left\{\, (-\infty, x) \ \middle|\ x\in\overline{\mathbb R}\,\right\}\ \cup\ \left\{\, (x, \infty) \ \middle|\  x\in\overline{\mathbb R}\,\right\}.
$$

Then $$\le_{\overline{\mathbb R}}\ \cap\ (\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)\quad=\quad \le_{\mathbb R}.$$

Comment: @Cristoph, I understand..thanks soo much!